# intersystems cache db insert/update/delete history

Tags: database, caching, intersystems

so I'm in the position of using a cache database.  Not my decision, I'm coming into the project with the view of it's a database, so all the naysayers please be respectable.  There's over 24 million rows per year added to this database so I'm looking for a way to do history on insert/update/delete.  In sql server we would create a database model, then run a tool to generate history tables in another database, and triggers to insert/update/delete.  e.g. [MyDatabase].[dbo].[Address], [MyDatabaseHistory].[dbo].[AddressHistory]...you get the idea...anyone out there with experience doing a similar thing to a cache database?

Answer (score 2):

In Caché you can also use triggers, please see in [documentation](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20151/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GSQL_triggers)